# XmlReader chopping off whitespace after ampersand entity?

Tags: wcf, escaping, entity, xmlreader

This is strange. I've got a WCF [Message](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.channels.message.aspx) and I'm trying to read the contents of the body into an XmlDocument. The contents of the message body look like this on the wire (when inspected with WCF tracing turned on):

```
<abc>
    <timeZone>(GMT-05:00) Eastern Time (US &amp; Canada)</timeZone>
</abc>
```

The code for the reader looks like this:

```
XmlReaderSettings settings = new XmlReaderSettings();
settings.IgnoreWhitespace = false;
settings.CheckCharacters = false;
XmlReader bodyReader = XmlReader.Create(
        message.GetReaderAtBodyContents().ReadSubtree(), settings);
XmlDocument messageDoc = new XmlDocument();
messageDoc.Load(bodyReader);
```

The resulting XML in `messageDoc` looks like this:

```
<abc>
    <timeZone>(GMT-05:00) Eastern Time (US &Canada)</timeZone>
</abc>
```

So where did the extra whitespace after the original `&amp;` go?

Comment: I couldn't reproduce your issue; whitespace was preserved in my test.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simplify the code by removing the `XmlReader`.  Then set the PreserveWhiteSpace on the `XmlDocument`.  You can replace all of your code with:

```
XmlDocument messageDoc = new XmlDocument() { PreserveWhitespace = true };
messageDoc.Load(message.GetReaderAtBodyContents().ReadSubtree());
```